# Audio tag in html can't find audio file

Tags: html, audio

I need to play an audio file using an  tag in my html page., but I can't see why it's not finding the source i'm passing to it.

```html
  <footer style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
    <audio controls id="audiofile" style="width: 750px;" preload="none">
      <source src="/home/tiziano/Desktop/Prova/flaskapp/templates/trim1_1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      Your browser does not support the audio element
    </audio>
  </footer>
```

I tried using the absolute and relative path but nothing changed.
When i load the page in localhost it says that can't find the file when it's actually there.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dot before your first slash ("./").

```
<source src="./home/tiziano/Desktop/Prova/flaskapp/templates/trim1_1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
```

Comment: Thanks but I just realized yesterday that flask only works with files that are inside "/static" directory. 
I just had to put files in there and it worked fine! Thanks anyway